# Unexpected results with cast()

Tags: r, casting, reshape

I am trying to cast data using `cast()` from the Reshape library, but I am getting unexpected results. I start with a dataframe that has lots of data in it, and `all_ia[all_ia$Student.ID == 102050,]` returns

```
66     102050        1      Mar
67     102050        0      Dec
68     102050        1      May
69     102050        0      Feb
```

Where the variables are Student.ID, Proficiency.Level, and testmonth respectively.

There are some Student.IDs with a 5th month, Sep.

When I run `all_ia.cast <- cast(all_ia, Student.ID ~ testmonth, value=c("Proficiency.Level"), fill=c("NA"))` and then run `all_ia.cast[all_ia.cast$Student.ID == 102050,]`, I get unexpected results:

```
1325    102050    1    1    1    1    NA
```

where the variables are Student.ID, Dec, Feb, Mar, May, Sep respectively. There is a warning when I run `cast()` which says `Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default`.

My question is, why is the fun.aggregate required and why are the Dec and Feb variables in the cast equal to 1 and not 0?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your casting formula `Student.Id ~ tesmonth` does not contain all of the variables in your data.frame, i.e. `Proficiency.Level` is not included.

This means, in general, that the casting has to perform an aggregation, and the aggregation formula defaults to `length`.

You seem to have a special case, where there is a one-to-one relationship between month and proficiency level for each student.  Therefore you should choose a aggregation function that preserves the data, e.g. taking the `mean`  The following should work:

```
cast(all_ia, Student.ID ~ testmonth, value=mean("Proficiency.Level"))
```

You don't supply test data, so this isn't tested.

Comment: Thank you! The cast you suggested above did not work letter for letter, but `all_ia.cast <- cast(all_ia, Student.ID ~ testmonth, value=c("Proficiency.Level"),fun.aggregate=mean)` did.

Comment: As a follow-up question, why is an aggregate function invoked when there is a one-to-one relationship? I feel like I haven't run into this problem in the past with other data with this relationship.

Comment: I don't know for sure.  Is it possible that `cast` takes a guess, but that you have duplicated rows?